# Rewrite cond regex to split an url with a /

Tags: 301-redirect, mod-rewrite

I'm struggling to correct the aftereffects a bogus redirect I made which led to a lot of 404s.
I need to 301 redirect URLs that look like

> example.com/xysometext

to

> example.com/xy/sometext

the `example.com/xy` and `example.com/xy/` parts are permanent, while `sometext` is unique for each page (i.e. `.*`)

I'm only starting to undestand mod-rewrite syntax, help much appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok I figured it out

> RewriteRule ^xy(.*)$ /xy/$1 [R=301,L]

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/xy/ [NC]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} ^/xy(.*)$ [NC]
RewriteRule .* http://www.example.org/xy/%1.html [R=301,L]
```

I think should do it. Please let me know and I can update the answer.

Comment: I hope you don't mind but I just added the 301 to the redirect statement otherwise the redirect wouldn't have been permanent.

Comment: @zigojacko Oddly, my personal example(s) had/have the 301 and I removed it because I always thought that R by default was a 301. The edit you made is safer and perhaps I should have left it. Good idea! Thanks.

Comment: hi, thanks. unfortunately it just redirects everything to /xy without adding sometext or even checking if it's xy (i.e. /nzsometext also redirects to /xy

Comment: @Easy Life Back to the drawing board! I will be experimenting with the regex and redirect and should return in a bit.

Comment: just to make it clear - i basically want to add a / i.e. .com/xysometext becomes .com/xy/sometext

Comment: @EasyLife I updated the answer. Your solution is great! Mine adds a bit of safety. (assuming I do not have a typo...) CONGRATS!!